# How to create an array of bytes to send to a BLE device and get a response from it?

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

There is lock that opens via bluetooth. Before working with the lock, you need to send a set of bytes, in response to which the device must return the key. Here is the instruction for compiling a set of bytes:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/z0nsoccz8or4kkf/Omni_OGB1_LOCK_Permenant_connection_smart_lock_Air_Interface_Protocol_V01_03_1%20%281%29.pdf?dl=0

Based on the data from the table of values required to obtain the key, an array of such values was obtained:

> FE 43 11 22 19 8A 60 65 7E 5C 46 41 8B F7 4D

Subscribe to the notification and write this set. But after not getting any notification when reading all the uuid get empty arrays

Questions:

1) do I make a byte array to send Correctly?

2) do I subscribe to the changes Correctly?

3) do we read the values Correctly to get answers or a key from the device?

4) How can I get an answer from the lock and pull out the key?

5) How to communicate with this device?

Class code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {
    var manager: CBCentralManager!
    var lock: CBPeripheral!
    var characteristicNot: CBCharacteristic!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }

    // Ищем устройство
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        if let name = peripheral.name {
            if name == "LOCK" {
                lock = peripheral
                lock.delegate = self
                manager.stopScan()
                manager.connect(lock, options: nil)
            }
        }
    }

    // Произошло подключение
    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        peripheral.delegate = self
        peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
    }

    // Ищем сервисы
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
        if let servicePeripheral = peripheral.services as [CBService]? {
            for service in servicePeripheral {
                peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
            }
        }
    }
    // Находим сервис
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

        if let characterArray = service.characteristics as [CBCharacteristic]? {

            for characteristic in characterArray {

                if characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB" {
                    print("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")
                }

                if characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "0783B03E-8535-B5A0-7140-A304D2495CB8" {
                    characteristicNot = characteristic
                    if characteristic.properties.contains(.read) {
                        print("\(characteristic.uuid): properties contains .read")
                    }

                    if characteristic.properties.contains(.notify) {
                        print("\(characteristic.uuid): properties contains .notify")
                    }

                    peripheral.discoverDescriptors(for: characteristic)
                    peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)

                    print("-------------------------")
                }

                if characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "0783B03E-8535-B5A0-7140-A304D2495CBA" {
                    if characteristic.properties.contains(.read) {
                        print("\(characteristic.uuid): properties contains .read")
                    }

                    if characteristic.properties.contains(.writeWithoutResponse) {
                        print("\(characteristic.uuid): properties contains .writeWithoutResponse")
                    }

                    let data:[UInt8] = [0xFE, 0x43, 0x11, 0x22, 0x19, 0x8A, 0x60, 0x65, 0x7E, 0x5C, 0x46, 0x41, 0x8B, 0xF7, 0x4D]
                    let writeData =  Data(bytes: data)

                    peripheral.writeValue(writeData, for: characteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse)

                    peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
                    peripheral.readValue(for: characteristicNot)
                    peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristicNot)

                    print("-------------------------")
                }

                if characteristic.uuid.uuidString == "0783B03E-8535-B5A0-7140-A304D2495CB9" {
                    if characteristic.properties.contains(.read) {
                        print("\(characteristic.uuid): properties contains .read")
                    }

                    if characteristic.properties.contains(.notify) {
                        print("\(characteristic.uuid): properties contains .notify")
                    }

                    if characteristic.properties.contains(.writeWithoutResponse) {
                        print("\(characteristic.uuid): properties contains .writeWithoutResponse")
                    }

                    print("-------------------------")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverDescriptorsFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        if let descriptorsArray = characteristic.descriptors as [CBDescriptor]? {
            for descriptor in descriptorsArray {
                print(descriptor)
            }
        }
    }
    // Читаем значения сервиса
    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        print("didUpdateValueFor characteristic", characteristic.uuid.uuidString)
        print("didUpdateValueFor characteristic value", characteristic.value)
        print("didUpdateValueFor characteristic error", error)

        if let characteristicData = characteristic.value {
            let byteArray = [UInt8](characteristicData)

            //let firstBitValue = byteArray[0] & 0x01
            print(byteArray)
        }

        print("-------------------------")
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateNotificationStateFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        print("didUpdateNotificationStateFor characteristic", characteristic.uuid.uuidString)
        print("didUpdateNotificationStateFor characteristic value", characteristic.value)
        print("didUpdateNotificationStateFor characteristic error", error)
        print("didUpdateNotificationStateFor characteristic descriptors", characteristic.descriptors)
        print("-------------------------")
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?) {
        print("didWriteValueFor characteristic", characteristic.uuid.uuidString)
        print("didWriteValueFor characteristic", characteristic.value)
        print("didWriteValueFor characteristic", error?.localizedDescription)
        print("-------------------------")
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didWriteValueFor descriptor: CBDescriptor, error: Error?) {
        print("didWriteValueFor descriptor")
    }

    func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor descriptor: CBDescriptor, error: Error?) {
         print("didUpdateValueFor descriptor")
    }


    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        var consoleLog = ""

        switch central.state {
        case .poweredOff:
            consoleLog = "BLE is powered off"
        case .poweredOn:
            consoleLog = "BLE is poweredOn"
            manager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
        case .resetting:
            consoleLog = "BLE is resetting"
        case .unauthorized:
            consoleLog = "BLE is unauthorized"
        case .unknown:
            consoleLog = "BLE is unknown"
        case .unsupported:
            consoleLog = "BLE is unsupported"
        default:
            consoleLog = "default"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to sound harsh but what's your actual problem ? Are you asking for validation of your code ? Just run it and see what happens, if something's going wrong, then please describe what's wrong.

Comment: The device should give me the key. But there is no response from the device.
First, I signed up for a character reference: -
peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)

The next step is to send an array of bytes, so I returned the key, but get no response: -
peripheral.writeValue(writeData, for: characteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse)

Comment: You should set notifications to true before you write the data and you should check for errors in your `didWrite` delegate method

Comment: Y, I have 2 characteristics with uuid - 0783b03e-8535-b5a0-7140-a304d2495cb8 (for notify), and 0783b03e-8535-b5a0-7140-a304d2495cba (for write). I set notifications (peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic) to true and then do write(peripheral.writeValue(writeData, for: characteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withoutResponse) , but I have no response from delegate methods, The program does not go into them.

Comment: Did you tried to write ```.withResponse``` ? Not without response.

Comment: Y, i tried it and I get error. (peripheral.writeValue(writeData, for: characteristic, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.withResponse). Then the code enters the delegate method and I get an error "Writing is not permitted."

Comment: That means you're writing on the wrong characteristic. This one doesn't accept write.

Comment: By this characteristic the following code gives "true". It turns out the entry without response - it solves.
 if characteristic.properties.contains(.writeWithoutResponse) {
                        print("\(characteristic.uuid): properties contains .writeWithoutResponse")
                    }